# How to connect tire to an external server?

Tags: ruby, tire

It should have been easy to find but somehow we didn't find out
How to connect tire* to an external server?

*Tire is A rich Ruby API and DSL for the ElasticSearch search engine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you mean different than `localhost:9200`, it should be something like this

```
require 'tire'

Tire.configure { url "http://ec2-232-10-73-111.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9200" }
```